# VBA If Statement with multiple arguments

Tags: excel, vba

---

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Fill the list box
   
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set ws = Worksheets("lstCategory")

    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 1
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then
            Me.lstCategories.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i

   
    'Setup the Tag property for easier access
    FirstName.Tag = "A"
    LastName.Tag = "B"
    Company.Tag = "C"
    dtCreated.Tag = "D"
    dtModified.Tag = "E"
    dtFollowUp.Tag = "F"
    Notes.Tag = "G"
    Address.Tag = "H"
    City.Tag = "I"
    State.Tag = "J"
    Zip.Tag = "K"
    Country.Tag = "L"
    BusPhone.Tag = "M"
    HomePhone.Tag = "N"
    lstCategories.Tag = "O"
    ckNonGmo.Tag = "P"
    ckOrganic.Tag = "Q"
    Email.Tag = "R"

    'Fill the textbox from the column specified by the Tag property
    Dim Ctl As Control
    For Each Ctl In Me.Controls
        If Ctl.Tag <> "" _
            Or Ctl.Tag <> "O" _
            Or Ctl.Tag <> "P" _
            Or Ctl.Tag <> "Q" Then
        Ctl = Sheet1.Cells(2, Ctl.Tag).Value
    'Debug.Print Ctl.Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

I am using a userform to update and add addresses to a salesman's database. The initialization worked beautifully until I added ORs of O P & Q to the if statement here at the end. They need special coding because they are a list box and check boxes. If I remove the ORs it works. If I leave them in I get an error 13 type mismatch. I've stared at it and stared at it...  Debug accepts it. Am I writing the IF statement wrong? All I'm trying to do is exclude the special controls.

Comment: Some languages use | or || for OR statements. Have you tried using those characters instead?

Comment: @TheGrandJ - not VBA though.

Comment: I don't see how your OR statement could ever return False but that (it) isn't the point. The error results from `Cells(2, Ctl.Tag)`, possibly when Ctl.Tag = "", and possibly because the column number is, well, a number. `Tag` is a Variant of String type. If you can fix your OR conditions to make sure that no "" is passed to the cell address `Cstr(Ctl.Tag)` should work. But if you want a number it would be `Columns(Ctl.Tag).Column`.

Comment: The "" part of the or statement works fine with the Cells... formula. It was when I tried to take out O P & Q that I had issues. How could "" be passed to the string? It's getting the control letters from above and using them as columns. The If statement takes out all controls that have no tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> If Ctl.Tag <> "" _
>     Or Ctl.Tag <> "O" _
>     Or Ctl.Tag <> "P" _
>     Or Ctl.Tag <> "Q" Then
> ```

If `Ctl.Tag` is "P", then it's not "", not "O", and it's not "Q" either ...and the whole expression is `True`.

If `Ctl.Tag` is "Q", then it's not "", not "O", and it's not "P" either ...and the whole expression is `True`.

If `Ctl.Tag` is "Z", then it's not "", not "O", it's not "P", and it's not "Q" ...and the whole expression is `True`.

If `Ctl.Tag` is an empty string, then it's not "O", "P", or "Q" ...and the whole expression is `True`.

No matter what value `Ctl.Tag` has, the Boolean expression systematically evaluates to `True`, because no matter what the value is, a predicate will be `True` - and the `Or` operator says the result is `True` if *either* operand is `True`.

You likely want the `And` operator here.

`And` requires *all* predicates to be `True` in order to evaluate to `True`, so...

```
 If Ctl.Tag <> "" _
     And Ctl.Tag <> "O" _
     And Ctl.Tag <> "P" _
     And Ctl.Tag <> "Q" Then
```

If `Ctl.Tag` is "P", then the whole expression is `False`.

If `Ctl.Tag` is "Q", then the whole expression is `False`.

If `Ctl.Tag` is "Z", then the whole expression is `True`.

If `Ctl.Tag` is an empty string, then the whole expression is `False`.

---

As for the *type mismatch* error, it's likely thrown here:

> ```
> Ctl = Sheet1.Cells(2, Ctl.Tag).Value
> ```

`Ctl` is declared as a `Control` object; this assignment misleadingly reads like you're assigning `Ctl` itself, but in reality you're just assigning its *default property*. This would be clearer / more explicit:

```
Ctl.Value = Sheet1.Cells(2, Ctl.Tag).Value
```

This instruction being allowed to run with `Ctl.Tag=""` should be a problem, but I would expect that to throw error 1004, not 13: there's likely something else going on.

We don't *know* that the value of the cell at row 2 and column `Crl.Tag` is usable. If it's an `#N/A` (or `#VALUE!`, `#REF!`, or any other) worksheet error, then `Range.Value` is a `Variant/Error` value, and you're trying to coerce that value into some `String` representation - but a `Variant/Error` can't be implicitly converted, and VBA throws a *type mismatch*. The solution is to first validate that the value isn't a `Variant/Error` value, using the `IsError` function:

```
If Not IsError(Sheet1.Cells(2, Ctl.Tag).Value) Then
    Ctl.Value = Sheet1.Cells(2, Ctl.Tag).Value
End If
```